# Bootstrap btn-group doesn't change radio buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So here is my markup

```
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="account-type" id="optionsRadios1" value="1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
User</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="account-type" id="optionsRadios2" value="2" checked> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
Special user</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="account-type" id="optionsRadios2" value="3"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
Agency</label>
</div>
```

It renders everything fine, the problem is that if I select value 3, it won't mark the third radio buttons as checked, or any other options if I select it, so when I submit the form, it doesn't matter which option I choose, the option that is checked by default, that will be submitted.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because you have the same id for these two radio buttons

```
  <input type="radio" name="account-type" id="optionsRadios2" value="2" checked>

  <input type="radio" name="account-type" id="optionsRadios2" value="3">
```

change the last to `id="optionsRadios3"`

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out, your third radio button id is wrong.

But that's not the problem:

The real problem is that you are loading jQueryUi AFTER bootstrap (i guess). This is a known 'bug'. Simply load jQueryUi BEFORE bootstrap and everything will work well

Answer (score -1):

Btn-group is a class attribute, it doesn't alter the behavior of your form.
When you need to choose from 3 radio buttons that exclude each other, then you should use the same name attribute for all of the radio buttons, rather than separate id's. 
I also guess that your  tag is surrounding these radio buttons, and we only see a part of your code, right?

Have a look at [this page](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/adding-a-radio-button-group-to-an-html-form/) to understand more about it.

Comment: That's not related to the question, even more his radio buttons name are correct