# Migrating from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3 cause btn-group toggle issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am migrating my code base from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3. I had a set of btn-groups that used to work fine in BS2 but finding it hard to get it work with BS3.
Buttons when clicked remain in active state and do not toggle unless clicked again.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="btnc-1" class="btn btn-default active">Gifts</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnc-2" class="btn btn-default">Apparels</button>   
    <button type="button" id="btnc-3" class="btn btn-default">Perfumes</button> 
</div>
```

Evne the BS page recommends a similar syntax so I don't feel or rather I couldn't see any problem with the syntax. I tried other similar questions on SO, this one being closest [Bootstrap btn-group doesn't change radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206303/bootstrap-btn-group-doesnt-change-radio-buttons) but couldn't find any working solution for my case. I have already taken care of the recommendations mentioned over there.

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What was the intended operation in Bootstrap 2? Running your code in JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6311/) with the Boostrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 CSS resulted in the same result...

Comment: The intended operation is to display a div relevant to that particular section and let the user know which button is active. Thanks for the fiddle, even I'm surprised how is it working in our development code with BS2. Is there anything that should be taken care for BS3, which I might have missed?

Comment: So only one button should be active at a time, correct?

Comment: @MikeKoch your example doesn't even have the javascript from bootstrap

Comment: @nol, it's in there. Check "external resources"

Comment: Yes @Mike thats correct, only one button should be active at a time.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to add the `data-toggle` html attribute in bootstrap 3 btn group automatically adds the active state by setting focus on the button. the psued class on `.btn:focus` makes it look like its active instead of adding the class active, if i am not mistaken. It makes better sense too because its accessible.

```
<div class="btn-group" >
<button type="button" id="btnc-1" class="btn btn-default">Gifts</button>
<button type="button" id="btnc-2" class="btn btn-default">Apparels</button>   
<button type="button" id="btnc-3" class="btn btn-default">Perfumes</button> 
 </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/ICiufEep2f#

if you must have the active class then add it and then use the below js via @Serlite

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").click(function(){
$(".btn-group > .btn").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[this was discussed on bootstrap 3 as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870671/bootstrap-3-btn-group-lose-active-class-when-click-any-where-on-the-page)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not restrict the requirement that only one button can be active at a time, per the OP's latest comment.

Comment: @nol, it doesn't make the button stay as active. Yes keeping the gifts button active on the page load is a requirement and when the other buttons get clicked only that button should be displayed as active (pressed state) and others should get inactive.

Comment: what i was trying to say is that you dont need the active class you can use the :focus to achieve what you want. And as far as the onload active then you will need js to set focus on the first one. Regardless the issue is caused by bootstrap 3 no longer using toggle att for btn groups. you will have to use javascript for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Bootstrap documentation (under JavaScript) there is a section for using buttons as radio buttons:

**Radio**

Add `data-toggle="buttons"` to a group of radio inputs for radio style toggling on btn-group.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

*Source:* http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Unfortunately, you will no longer be able to use the `button` tag for each button, as there is no way (as far as I know) to indicate that the button is of type "radio".

You could also use some JavaScript to remove the "active" state of the other buttons when they are clicked, however this code block here (and from http://getbootstrap.com) will ensure that the buttons are treated as  group of radio buttons.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6314/

Comment: I agree if button tags have to be done away then your suggestions will definitely come to the rescue. Not sure how BootStrap is achieving it on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups. The only catch is if you see this BS reference on Chrome you will see the desired effect, I tried it on safari and it didn't behave as expected. There they are using the regular button tags, which is working exactly the way I want but somehow I am not able to replicate that. Not sure if there is any browser specific feature that is enabling/disabling the desired behaviour.

Comment: I'm currently running Windows, so I don't have Safari.  However I can confirm that it does work on Chrome, IE, and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6315/.... strange!

But at the same time, this won't let you have an "active" button on load, as the active button can never be deselected.